# Fuzzy Text Search: Regex Wildcard Search Generator?

Tags: php, regex, ocr, fuzzy-search, fuzzy-comparison

I'm wondering if there is some kind of way to do fuzzy string matching in PHP. Looking for a word in a long string, finding a potential match even if its mis-spelled; something that would find it if it was off by one character due to an OCR error.

I was thinking a regex generator might be able to do it. So given an input of "crazy" it would generate this regex:

```
.*((crazy)|(.+razy)|(c.+azy)|cr.+zy)|(cra.+y)|(craz.+)).*
```

It would then return all matches for that word or variations of that word.

**How to build the generator:**
I would probably split the search string/word up into an array of characters and build the regex expression doing a foreach the newly created array replacing the key value (the position of the letter in the string) with ".+".

Is this a good way to do fuzzy text search or is there a better way? What about some kind of string comparison that gives me a score based on how close it is? I'm trying to see if some badly converted OCR text contains a word in short.

Comment: Your regex is wrong - replace `+` with `.`

Comment: thanks for the tip, fixed the question with .+

Comment: `c.+azy` will match `calksjdazy` - `c` followed by one or more characters followed by `azy`. For a single character, use `c.azy`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

String distance functions are useless when you don't know what the right word is. I'd suggest pspell functions:

```
$p = pspell_new("en");
print_r(pspell_suggest($p, "crazzy"));
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pspell-suggest.php

Comment: Ah, it shows that I'm a PHP novice: I never heard of that method! Excellent suggestion, this should be voted up. +1

Comment: +1 for showing that there's something new to learn every day!  However note that `pspell_suggest`, when given a correctly spelled word, will _not_ give you options for misspelling.  Hence it will not really work what the OP needs.

Answer (score 2):

```
    echo generateRegex("crazy");
    function generateRegex($word)
    {
      $len = strlen($word);
      $regex = "\b((".$word.")";
      for($i = 0; $i < $len; $i++)
      {
        $temp = $word;
        $temp[$i] = '.';
        $regex .= "|(".$temp.")";
      }
      $regex = $regex.")\b";
      return $regex;
    }
```

Comment: OP asked for a PHP-based solution.

Comment: Agreed. But how hard it is to translate this?

Comment: translated to php - click on the viewsource link in the diff to see java version.

Answer (score 1):

Levenshtein is one example of a String [Edit-distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edit_distance). There are different metrics for different purposes. Familiarize yourself with them and find the one that works for you.