# How to find exact or closest match from a large array, in a big string?

Tags: php, math

Consider the following. I have a very large array with all the road names in a given country, ordered by string length like this:

```
$roadNames = ['Ivy Lane','East Road','The Maltings','Greenhill Road', 'Woodlands Close']; //And many, many more
```

Now i want look for an exact match in a in a long string

```
$string = "
..... ALOT OF TEXT ..... 
..... ALOT OF TEXT ..... 

You can find us at: Greenhill Road 1, 11111, The City 

..... ALOT OF TEXT .....
..... ALOT OF TEXT ..... 
";
```

To find an exact match, witch is fairly easy, I just do the following:

```
foreach ($roadNames as $roadName) {
    if(stripos($string, $roadName) !== false){
        echo 'Exact match: '.$roadName;
        break;
    }
}
```

But what if the road name is misspelled by 1 letter, fx. an extra space / a space is missing, a letter less/more, or 1 letter is wrong. Fx. "Greenhil Road", "Greenhilll Road", "GreenhillRoad", "Green hill Road", "Creenhill Road"? How can i now find the best match of all my road names in the array if the the road name in the $string was one of the examples? Is there any mathematics way to do it? Or maybe i can buid a regex?

I am thinking something like this, although it seems like overkill (And does not work)

```
foreach ($roadNames as $roadName) {
    if (stripos($string, $roadName)) {
        echo 'Exact match: ' . $roadName;
        break;
    } else {
        $alphabet = range('a', 'z');
        $alphabet[] = ' ';
        $roadName_split = str_split($roadName);
        $test_array = array();
        foreach ($roadName_split as $strpos => $letter) {
            foreach ($alphabet as $letter_in_alphabet) {
                $test_array[] = $letter_in_alphabet;
            }
            foreach ($test_array as $key => $value) {
                $test_array[$key] .= substr($roadName, $strpos, 1);
            }
        }
        echo '<pre>';
        print_r($test_array);
        echo '</pre>';
        die;
        foreach ($test_array as $misplled_value) {
            if (stripos($string, $misplled_value)) {
                echo 'close match found: ' . $roadName;
                break;
            }
        }
//        OR Some kind of a regex, dont know how it should be
//        $roadName_split = str_split($roadName);
//        $re = '';
//        foreach ($roadName_split as $strpos => $letter) {
//            $re .= "$letter?";
//        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This -
article: https://www.phpclasses.org/package/4859-PHP-Suggest-corrected-spelling-text-in-pure-PHP.html

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Sounds horrible.  Perhaps: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.similar-text.php

Comment: Note if your text includes "Greenhill Road" then your "exact match" code is going to match on "Hill Road" first.

Comment: If you want to do fuzzy matching, then you'll first need to extract what you think is a road name from the text. Given that, you can use something like [levenshtein()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.levenshtein.php) or [similar_text()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.similar-text.php).

Comment: `SOUNDEX()` sounds like,  might also be an option.

Comment: Alex, your are right, the roadNames should be in reversed order, so longest road name is the first key, and the shortest road name is the last key, and then it should match "Greenhill Road" before "Hill Road"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a solution with inspiration from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1720798/2192013

I make a regex from each roadName, allowing 1 letter to be misspelled, 1 letter or space, too short or too much, with this function:

```
function generateRegex($word) {
    $len = strlen($word);
    $regex = "/(($word)";
    $word_split = str_split($word);
    foreach ($word_split as $strpos => $letter) {
        $temp = $word;
        $temp[$strpos - 1] = '.';
        if ($strpos === 0) {
            $temp1 = substr($word, ($strpos + 1));
            $temp2 = '.' . substr($word, $strpos);
        } else {
            $temp1 = substr($word, 0, $strpos) . substr($word, ($strpos + 1));
            $temp2 = substr($word, 0, $strpos) . '.' . substr($word, $strpos);
        }
        $regex .= "|($temp)";
        $regex .= "|($temp1)";
        $regex .= "|($temp2)";
    }
    $regex = $regex . ")/mi";
    return $regex;
}
```

1. $temp take cares of 1 letter misspelled (Ex. Creenhill Road) and are
   replacing 1 letter with a dot, as many times as possible
2. $temp1 takes care of 1 letter/space too short (Ex. Grenhill Road OR
   GreenhillRoad) and are removing 1 letter, as many times as possible
3. $temp2 takes care of 1 letter/space too much (Ex. Green hill Road OR
   Greennhill Road) and are adding a dot to each letter, as many times
   as possible

So the final script looks like this:

```
function generateRegex($word) {
    $len = strlen($word);
    $regex = "/(($word)";
    $word_split = str_split($word);
    foreach ($word_split as $strpos => $letter) {
        $temp = $word;
        $temp[$strpos - 1] = '.';
        if ($strpos === 0) {
            $temp1 = substr($word, ($strpos + 1));
            $temp2 = '.' . substr($word, $strpos);
        } else {
            $temp1 = substr($word, 0, $strpos) . substr($word, ($strpos + 1));
            $temp2 = substr($word, 0, $strpos) . '.' . substr($word, $strpos);
        }
        $regex .= "|($temp)";
        $regex .= "|($temp1)";
        $regex .= "|($temp2)";
    }
    $regex = $regex . ")/mi";
    return $regex;
}

function findBestMatch($roadNames, $string) {
    foreach ($roadNames as $roadName) {
        if (stripos($string, $roadName)) {
            $return = 'Exact match found: ' . $roadName;
            break;
        } else {
            $re = generateRegex($roadName);
            if (preg_match($re, $string)) {
                $return = 'Close match found: ' . $roadName;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    if (!isset($return) OR empty($return)) {
        return 'Match not found';
    } else {
        return $return;
    }
}

$roadNames = ['Greenhill Road', 'Ivy Lane', 'East Road', 'The Maltings', 'Woodlands Close']; //And many, many more
$misspelled_examples = ['Greenhill Road', 'Crennhill Road', 'Green hill Road', 'Greennhill Road', 'GreenhillRoad', 'Grenhill Road', 'GrenhilRoad'];

foreach ($misspelled_examples as $value) {
    $strings[] = "
..... ALOT OF TEXT ..... 
..... ALOT OF TEXT ..... 

You can find us at: $value 1, 11111, The City 

..... ALOT OF TEXT .....
..... ALOT OF TEXT ..... 
";
}

foreach ($strings as $key => $string) {
    echo 'Input road-name: ' . $misspelled_examples[$key];
    echo '<br>';
    echo findBestMatch($roadNames, $string);
    echo '<hr>';
}
```